# Flight cancellations in Ladakh

Tags: air-travel, india, air-india, kingfisher-airlines

How often do the flights get canceled due to bad weather (or any other reason) from Leh to Delhi in May?

If a flight does get canceled, what are the policies for dealing with that for [AirIndia](http://www.airindia.in) and [Kingfisher Airlines](http://www.flykingfisher.com/)?

What I primarily want to know is whether I get to go on the next available flight for free if my flight was canceled.

Answer (score 6):

According to [Flightstats.com](http://www.flightstats.com/go/FlightRating/flightRatingByRoute.do) for flights from IXL to DEL, you really want to go to Air India.  Their cancellation rates are almost nil, and way ahead of GoAir and Jet Airways.  It doesn't mention Kingfisher, however.

Air India's [policy on cancellation, refunds and the like is available on their webpage](http://airindia.in/SBCMS/Webpages/Refund-Cancelations-Rebooking-Faq.aspx?MID=206).  It's long, but basically there are a few rules about when they can cancel, when you'll get a refund, and to let you know even if you get a refund, there's an admin fee for said refund.

Comment: Is `delay` displayed in hours on that website? I already booked three flights from Kingfisher and only had pleasant experiences so would like to book their flight once again. Besides, it's some 60 bucks cheaper in April. What I primarily want to know is whether I get to go on the next available flight for free if my flight was canceled.

Answer (score 4):

Air India is the national, government-owned airline of India. Because of this, it has a mandate to run on less popular sectors and provide them air connectivity, even if it is at the expense profitability. Private airlines like Kingfisher, GoAir (not to be confused with Indigo), and Jet Airways sometimes do cancel flights if seat occupancy on any particular day is low. So for a sector like Jammu & Kashmir, I would go with Air India.

Comment: Source: My dad has to fly around India for a work a lot, and on the less popular sectors he always flies Air India because it's less prone to cancellations.

Comment: It is advisable to avoid (at least for few months) Kingfisher Airlines keeping in mind the crisis the airlines undergoing in the recent days.

Comment: @Ankur Banerjee Thanks a lot for this.  I was not aware of that rule.  This info sure helps when we travel to tourist spots.  One similar thing that helped me was - I had a connecting flight - one was very late, but since they both belonged to same airline, they allowed me on next available one.  I did not know that.